# Cubic 3d perlin noise function?

Tags: noise

I would like to make some 3d procedural architecture with isosurfaces, so i need to make space into cubic wall shapes and then to subdivide each wall into intricate grids, bars, diamond patterns etc.

Can someone tell me some mathematic tricks to make a 3d isofield similar to 3d perlin noise, except with cubes, all orthogonal, to use as a starting function on which to base procedural architecture isosurfaces?

-edit- : i think that one way to make a cubig 3d perlin function is to deconstruct it into 3x 1d perlin wavelike functions, you know random sinusoidal looking 1d perlin, and quantize it so that each of the 3 1d components is either -1 or 1, and then make 3d perlin from those 3 components.

ill try to figure it out myself, using the following code (sorry its a maths question that has become a programming one!), although if someone can see how to quantize this simplex noise into only -1 an 1 or 0 and 1 values prior to being folded into 3d, please enlighten me!

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

public class SimplexNoiseGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
private int[] A = new int[3];
private float s, u, v, w;
private int i, j, k;
private float onethird = 0.333333333f;
private float onesixth = 0.166666667f;
private int[] T;

public SimplexNoiseGenerator() {
    if (T == null) {
        System.Random rand = new System.Random();
        T = new int[8];
        for (int q = 0; q < 8; q++)
            T[q] = rand.Next();
    }
}

public SimplexNoiseGenerator(string seed) {
   T = new int[8];
   string[] seed_parts = seed.Split(new char[] {' '});

   for(int q = 0; q < 8; q++) {
     int b;
     try {
      b = int.Parse(seed_parts[q]);
     } catch {
      b = 0x0;
     }
     T[q] = b;
   }
}

public SimplexNoiseGenerator(int[] seed) { // {0x16, 0x38, 0x32, 0x2c, 0x0d, 0x13, 0x07, 0x2a}
   T = seed;
}

public string GetSeed() {
   string seed = "";

   for(int q=0; q < 8; q++) {
     seed += T[q].ToString();
     if(q < 7)
      seed += " ";
   }

   return seed;
}

public float coherentNoise(float x, float y, float z, int octaves=1, int multiplier = 25, float amplitude = 0.5f, float lacunarity = 2, float persistence = 0.9f) {
   Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(x,y,z)/multiplier;
   float val = 0;
   for (int n = 0; n < octaves; n++) {
     val += noise(v3.x,v3.y,v3.z) * amplitude;
     v3 *= lacunarity;
     amplitude *= persistence;
   }
   return val;
}

public int getDensity(Vector3 loc) {
   float val = coherentNoise(loc.x, loc.y, loc.z);
   return (int)Mathf.Lerp(0,255,val);
}

// Simplex Noise Generator
public float noise(float x, float y, float z) {
    s = (x + y + z) * onethird;
    i = fastfloor(x + s);
    j = fastfloor(y + s);
    k = fastfloor(z + s);

    s = (i + j + k) * onesixth;
    u = x - i + s;
    v = y - j + s;
    w = z - k + s;

    A[0] = 0; A[1] = 0; A[2] = 0;

    int hi = u >= w ? u >= v ? 0 : 1 : v >= w ? 1 : 2;
    int lo = u < w ? u < v ? 0 : 1 : v < w ? 1 : 2;

    return kay(hi) + kay(3 - hi - lo) + kay(lo) + kay(0);
}

float kay(int a) {
    s = (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]) * onesixth;
    float x = u - A[0] + s;
    float y = v - A[1] + s;
    float z = w - A[2] + s;
    float t = 0.6f - x * x - y * y - z * z;
    int h = shuffle(i + A[0], j + A[1], k + A[2]);
    A[a]++;
    if (t < 0) return 0;
    int b5 = h >> 5 & 1;
    int b4 = h >> 4 & 1;
    int b3 = h >> 3 & 1;
    int b2 = h >> 2 & 1;
    int b1 = h & 3;

    float p = b1 == 1 ? x : b1 == 2 ? y : z;
    float q = b1 == 1 ? y : b1 == 2 ? z : x;
    float r = b1 == 1 ? z : b1 == 2 ? x : y;

    p = b5 == b3 ? -p : p;
    q = b5 == b4 ? -q : q;
    r = b5 != (b4 ^ b3) ? -r : r;
    t *= t;
    return 8 * t * t * (p + (b1 == 0 ? q + r : b2 == 0 ? q : r));
}

int shuffle(int i, int j, int k) {
    return b(i, j, k, 0) + b(j, k, i, 1) + b(k, i, j, 2) + b(i, j, k, 3) + b(j, k, i, 4) + b(k, i, j, 5) + b(i, j, k, 6) + b(j, k, i, 7);
}

int b(int i, int j, int k, int B) {
    return T[b(i, B) << 2 | b(j, B) << 1 | b(k, B)];
}

int b(int N, int B) {
    return N >> B & 1;
}

int fastfloor(float n) {
    return n > 0 ? (int)n : (int)n - 1;
}
```

}

Comment: on revisiting this question. i figure using a square interpolation function would make a square perlin result. so the interpolation function should flip from 0 to 1 in the middle, if larger.5 =1 if smaller.5 =0, kind of noise interpolation.